# Como uma classe pode também ser um método em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, classes

Veja a classe `Integer`:

```
Integer.class
=> Class
```

Parece também que ela é um método, ao mesmo tempo que é uma classe:

```
Integer 10.5
=> 10
```

Como isso é possível em Ruby? Onde esse método está definido? Que mecanismos o Ruby utiliza para saber se estou chamando o método ou a classe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como isso é possível em Ruby?

Assim:

```ruby
class C
  attr_accessor :x
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end
end

# N.B.
def C(x)
  C.new(x)
end
```

repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/CurvyTerrificRegister.

> Onde esse método está definido?

Isso é um método do objeto `main`. A classe deste objeto é [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html). Esta classe inclui o módulo [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html). [Documentação do método](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer).

> Que mecanismos o Ruby utiliza para saber se estou chamando o método ou a classe?

Chamadas de método são sempre a passagem de mensagens:

- `C.new(42)` = enviar a mensagem `new` para o objeto `C`.
- `C(42)` = enviar a mensagem `C` para o objeto `main`.

<sup>(Eu pessoalmente acho isso confuso. Eu não usaria isso.)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Pode complementá-la com as outras perguntas da questão? "Como isso é possível em Ruby? Onde esse método está definido? Que mecanismos o Ruby utiliza para saber se estou chamando o método ou a classe?"

Comment: @vnbrs Por favor, veja a edição.